# Reg Exp for finding hashtag words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following sentence as a test:

```
This is a test with #shouldshow and to see if there #show
#yes this#shouldnotshow what is going on here
```

I have figured out most of the Reg Exp I need.  Here's what I have so far:  `/((?<=#)([A-Z]*))/gi`

This matches every tag but also matches the `shouldnotshow` portion.  I want to not match words that are prefixed by anything but # (excluding whitespace & \n).

So the only matched words I should get are: `shouldshow` `show` `yes`.
Note: after #show is a newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to see if the hash is prefixed with whitespace or starts the string

https://regex101.com/r/JDuGvr/1

```
/(\s|^)#(\w+)/gm
```

with positive lookbehind as OP used

https://regex101.com/r/06X3ZX/1

```
/(?<=(\s|^)#)(\w+)/gm;
```

use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` if you do not want an underscore

```js
const re1 = /(\s|^)#(\w+)/gm; 
const re2 = /(?<=(\s|^)#)(\w+)/gm; 

const str = `This is a test with #shouldshow and to see if there #show
#yes this#shouldnotshow what is going on here`;

const res1 = [...str.matchAll(re1)].map(match => match[2]); // here the match is the third item
console.log(res1)

const res2 = [...str.matchAll(re2)].map(match => match[0]); // match is the first item
console.log(res2)
```

Comment: just to ensure I had the words without hashtag I adjusted to the following `(?<=(\s|^)#)(\w+)`

Comment: My assumption without research would be that the complexity between the two solutions is inconsequential so more so just preference and having the logic that spits out the tags be isolated to the regexp itself.

Comment: I see. I updated the answer to show the difference. I have not yet used lookahead/behind

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I haven't done a ton of regexp so I'm no master but your solution helped me see other ways to accomplish it

Comment: Likewise. I have to look at lookbehind more and use the non-capturing groups more

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using your pattern asserting a `#` on the left that does not have a non whitespace char before it using `(?<!\S)#` and get the match only without capture groups.

Match at least 1+ times a char A-Z to prevent matching an empty string.

```
(?<=(?<!\S)#)[A-Z]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H018ig/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=(?<!\S)#)[A-Z]+/gi;
const str = `This is a test with #shouldshow and to see if there #show
#yes this#shouldnotshow what is going on her`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```